# Codeigniter File upload with no extension

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, frameworks

The allowed type is *. Hence I can upload any file using Codeigniter Do Upload function.
But the problem is when the file do not have any extension, then the filename itself become extension. like filename is xyz then uploaded file will be xyz.xyz    .I want the file as it is. There is no problem when the extension is there. Only problem with non-extension file.

Comment: Hey check the part of the function which checks for the extension and if did not find an extension then use the file name as extension , can you please upload the code for Do upload function ?

Answer (score 0):

For easy solution, you can modify the codeigniter Upload library(/system/libraries/Upload.php). At the beginning of get_extension() function, add this line:

```
if(strpos($filename, '.') === FALSE))return '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever try to edit the core system library, you can however extend the library and change whatever you need, i've faced a similar one when i tried to upload a blob from form data then i found that codeigniter upload library extracts the extension form the uploaded file name not the mime type and the only dummp solution to this is to accept '*' but then you will face tons of other problems and will allow all types by default. Anyways you can just extend the upload library as MY_Upload and edit the get_extension() by adding just one line like this:

```
public function get_extension($filename)
{
    $x = explode('.', $filename);

    if (count($x) === 1)
    {
        $x = strtok(strstr($this->file_type, '/'), '/');    // get ext from mime
        return $x ? '.'.$x : '';
    }

    $ext = ($this->file_ext_tolower) ? strtolower(end($x)) : end($x);
    return '.'.$ext;
}
```

btw, i was able to fix my problem by changing the filename in form data like this:`append('image', blob, 'image.png')` and avoided the problem of passing an image name without extension.